# Google Chrome URLAllowlist doesn't work on win 10 pro

Tags: windows, google-chrome, url-scheme

I was adding to the URLAllowlist a new scheme and for some reason on some of the win 10 pro-PCs it works and on some, it doesn't.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution using a different policy:

adding to this registry path [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
a new "AutoLaunchProtocolsFromOrigins"="[{"allowed_origins": ["*"], "protocol": "yourNewScheme"}]"

it will also work for edge under:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]

[image]

Comment: Does this really work for you? I just tried all the options: `AutoLaunchProtocolsFromOrigins`, `ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox`, `URLAllowlist` – nothing works. Edge always shows «This site is trying to open ...» – even if it's just a new tab. No any checkboxes appering, neither. I made sure the policies displayed on edge://policy, so Edge knows it's enabled but it's just... Not working. Windows 10

Comment: Huh, just found out it actually kinda works... It works if I press such an link with such an url on a page. But it doesn't work when I try to open such urls using «search engines» functionality, which is precisely my use-case – and it still shows the popup. Heck, that's annoying...